# Synaptics touchpad not working properly on HP ProBook 4540S

Tags: windows-7, synaptics-touchpad

I recently bought an HP ProBook 4540S. The touchpad works smoothly on the left side. At the right side, scrolling works, but tapping won't.

Is this a software or hardware problem?

Comment: Have you installed the current version of the driver for your trackpad?

Comment: Yes i hav installed the synaptic touch pad driver but still can't work

Comment: Have you contacted HP for assistance with this matter?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found that the Synaptics touchpad setup was not compatible with HP 4540S and I tried for setup with HP drivers from the Internet. Now it works properly. It wasn't a hardware issue after all.